# Using Realm with Multi-tenant Postgresql Schemas

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

My app is a multi-tenant service where each tenant's data is separated into their own postgresql schema. How would someone get the Realm platform working with this kind of setup?

Answer (score 0):

Realm has a Postgres adapter, which might be useful for you. See https://docs.realm.io/platform/using-synced-realms/server-side-usage/data-integration for details.